# Function not working in this specific code - interprets wrong "if" statement - Python

Tags: python, control-flow

Python function that I just wrote is keep on looping up to a hundred.
On the interpreter (or rather RUN), I am entering "5", but it executes the wrong "if" statement.

```
def range_v2(c):
    int(c)
    if c == 5:
        for x in range(1, 50, +5):
            print(x)
    else:
        for x in range(0, 100, +5):
            print(x)

y = input()
int(y)
range_v2(y)
```

Comment: What's wrong here? What's wanted behavior?

Comment: Try with c = int(c).

Comment: @JimmyBernljung That's the answer. Thanks

Comment: You don't need to set the input as an `int` twice by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int(c)` doesn't in-place convert `c` to an `int` if that's what you think it does. You'd have to do

```
c = int(c)
```

Comment: @JimmyBernljung because He came up with the answer first

Answer (score 3):

You are redefining your "c" variable in the function. Your function accepts an argument called "c" and then in the first line of the function you set the value of "c" to 0, so no matter what argument you pass to the function, it will always be evaluated for 0. Remove the line "c=0" and it should work how you expect.